# TreeView with CheckBoxes dynamically WPF. How to know the name of the elements selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, treeview

I have a code that displays the files and folders names in a TreeView and put a checkbox from each element. What I don't know how to do is how to know the elements in the TreeView that are selected with the checkboxes.

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5,0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Program:

```
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
    treeView.Items.Add(getTree(di));

    public TreeViewItem getTree(DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
        item.Header = di.Name;
        item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
        foreach (DirectoryInfo s in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            item.Items.Add(getTree(s)); 
        }
        foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
        {
            item.Items.Add(fi.Name);
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: While it is possible to traverse the items in the `TreeView` manually, I would suggest you to change your code to the MVVM approach. Then, you can simple traverse your view model items without needing to bother about the view's properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own `TreeViewItem` type:

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; } = new List<Node>();
}
```

Add instance of this type to the `TreeView`:

```
public Node getTree(DirectoryInfo di)
{
    Node item = new Node();
    item.Name = di.Name;
    foreach (DirectoryInfo s in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        item.Children.Add(getTree(s));
    }
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        item.Children.Add(new Node { Name = fi.Name });
    }
    return item;
}
```

Bind to the properties of this type in the view:

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" Grid.Row="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You could then iterate through the items recursively and check the value of the `IsChecked` property:

```
private List<string> GetSelectedNames()
{
    List<string> selectedNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in treeView.Items.OfType<Node>())
        GetSelected(item, ref selectedNames);
    return selectedNames;
}

public void GetSelected(Node node, ref List<string> s)
{
    if (node.IsChecked)
        s.Add(node.Name);

    foreach (Node child in node.Children)
        GetSelected(child, ref s);
}
```

If you want to take this a step further, you bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `TreeView` to an `IEnumerable<Node>` property of your view model and iterate through this one instead of the `Items` property of the `TreeView` control.