# Traversing a TreeView

Tags: c#, tree

I'm working on a WPF project where I populate a TreeView (MainWindow.xaml) using a class called `SampleTreeItem`. This TreeView shows files from the selected folder. When a user clicks the tree item (mainWindow.cs), the code in the background opens the file, serializes it and extract the data from it.

Now I'm adding a CheckBox to this tree through the `SampleTreeView` class using a header template, so each item in the TreeView on Mainwindow.xaml is an instance of the `SampleTreeView` class.

Now in Mainwindow.xaml there are two different tabs. I want my TreeView to show CheckBoxes when it is on tab1 and hide them if tab2 is selected. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void tabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ItemCollection coll = filesTreeView.Items;
    foreach (TreeViewItem i in coll)
    {
        //checkboxes visible
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'sender' that gets passed in will be your tabControl.  You can cast it to a TabControl to determine which one it is, which gives you your condition on showing checked or not.

Comment: Yes you are right. see the following code.

Comment: I did some thing like this :

Comment: if (e.Source is System.Windows.Controls.TabControl ) and then checked which tab is selected. This works fine. The main issue is finding the status of CheckBoxes.

Comment: See this answer for details on a custom implementation:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150421/treeview-with-checkboxes-dynamically-wpf-how-to-know-the-name-of-the-elements-s